# How to 3d render nifti file surfaces without GUI interaction in CPU only mode?

Tags: animation, rendering, surface, 3d-rendering, nifti

my goal is to create 3d surface renderings for a huge stack of mri scans in nifti format. The process needs to be completely automised and run without GUI interaction in CPU only mode as the script is supposed to run in a docker container. Is there a package to achieve that?

The resulting images should look like this one:
[image: The resulting images should look like this]

What would be really nice is if I could animate the result to rotate around the different perspectives. Like in this tutorial here, which requires GUI interaction unfortunately:
https://mollermara.com/blog/blender-brain/